# How to get the average for one column of data in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

My goal is List employees that have greater than average education level

Here is what i have

```
Select  [ED_LVL],
   AVG (ED_LVL) as 'AVG ED_LVL'
   From [Enterprise].[dbo].[Employee]
   Group BY [ED_LVL]
```

I'm guessing i have to make some type of subquery or partition? not sure how to do this
thanks!

Comment: use "HAVING" clause to filter aggr.

Comment: @yswai1986 - Could you show a sample with `Having`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
Select  *
From [Enterprise].[dbo].[Employee]
WHERE ED_LVL > (Select  AVG(ED_LVL) From [Enterprise].[dbo].[Employee])
```

Comment: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

This is how average function can be used:

```
SELECT AVG(column_name) FROM table_name
```

Regarding to you question, try this:

```
Select  * FROM [Enterprise].[dbo].[Employee] 
WHERE [ED_LVL]>(SELECT AVG(ED_LVL) FROM [Enterprise].[dbo].[Employee])
```

Which gives Employee details Whose ED_LVL is greater than average ED_LVL.

Comment: Who asked you for Syntax of `AVG` Function?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select *
from Employee t
where t.ED_LVL >
(
    select AVG(e.ED_LVL) [avg]
    from Employee e
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this !!

```
 SELECT  [ED_LVL],
    FROM (
      SELECT
         [ED_LVL],
        AVG( [ED_LVL]) OVER () AS  avg_edu,
      FROM [Enterprise].[dbo].[Employee]
    ) s
    WHERE [ED_LVL]> avg_edu
```